# I get this error while running eas: "zsh: command not found: eas"

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, eas

I'm not sure if this is a common error but I recently ran into this and it took me quite a bit to get this fixed. If any other answers ?

please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred probably because the dependency which you're installing is not being installed globaly, so you'll need to change the "PATH" so it installs globaly.

If you've already ran:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

and you still get nothing, you'll most likely need to change the node_module PATH:

```
mkdir "${HOME}/.npm-packages"

NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"

prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages

NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"

PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"

unset MANPATH

MANPATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/share/man:$(manpath)"
```

then run:

```
npm install -g eas
```

Hope this helped you, if not good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I tried all of this and it didn't work for me. It seems like such a rubbish process that you install EAS and then you can't use EAS without errors.... It's worked for me in the past!

Comment: @Frankinstyyn I completely agree, but I’ve noticed that this is a mac thing if you’re on mac. Try re-installing node.js maybe ‍♂️